# How to copy or import database from mongolab.com to my local mongodb server?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, monk

I have used some queries for import and export database from mongolab.com to my local mongodb server. Can you please anyone tell me, how to retrieve all data from mongolab.com (clouddb) to local mongodb server.

I have trying these codes in my local mongodb server with command line prompt:

```
mongodump -h ds040032.mongolab.com:40032 -d mydb -u "<"myname">" -p "<"mypass">" -o "<"D:\2016\LearnMongoDB\NEWDB">"

mongoexport -h ds040032.mongolab.com:40032 -d mydb -c "<"collectionname">" -u "<"myname">" -p "<"mypass">" -o "<"D:\2016\LearnMongoDB\Testingf">"

mongorestore -h ds040032.mongolab.com:40032 -d mydb -u "<"myname">" -p "<"mypass">" "<"input db directory">"
```

After entering, I am not getting any results with the commandline prompt. Getting `Still cursor loading` symbol.

Comment: Refer to this : http://docs.mlab.com/backups/

Once the backup is created, download the file, extract it, and then use `mongorestore` to restore your backup to your local machine.

Comment: Ok Thanks for refer it.

Answer (score 2):

try [db.copyDatabase](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.copyDatabase/)

```
    db.copyDatabase('from_mydb','to_mydb','ds040032.mongolab.com:40032',
'<myname>','<mypassword>')
```

Go to local mongo shell and apply above command with appropriate parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In 2017, `db.copyDatabase` (using shell) works, but the format has changed a bit:

```
db.copyDatabase('mlab_databse_name', 'local_folder_for_data_name', 'ds000000.mlab.com:00000', 'database_user_name', 'database_user_password')
```

Comment: i don't find any differences here do you guys ?

Comment: It is minimal thus can be easilly missed and cause errors: change "mongolab" to "mlab". That is it.